# How to Calculate Heroku Postgres DB Memory Utilization in %?

Tags: heroku-postgres

**How to calculate Heroku Postgres DB Memory Utilization in % using below values.**

**Raw data**

```
2013-05-07T17:41:06+00:00 
source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_VIOLET 
addon=postgres-metric-68904 
sample#current_transaction=1873 
sample#db_size=26219348792bytes 
sample#tables=13 
sample#active-connections=92 
sample#waiting-connections=1 
sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99723 
sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.99118 
sample#load-avg-1m=1.42 
sample#load-avg-5m=1.45 
sample#load-avg-15m=1.34 
sample#read-iops=0 
sample#write-iops=2.875 
sample#memory-total=1692568kB 
sample#memory-free=73876kB 
sample#memory-cached=1344128kB 
sample#memory-postgres=22388kB
```

I want to calculate percentage using below value.

```
sample#memory-total=1692568kB 
sample#memory-free=73876kB 
sample#memory-cached=1344128kB 
sample#memory-postgres=22388kB
```

Answer (score 2):

Divide the total reported memory total by the plan-specific amount of RAM then multiply by 100 for a percentage.

(`sample#memory-total` / [available mem in kb](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-production-tier-technical-characterization#performance-characteristics)) * 100